# How to add an option to the top of an existing spinner in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, spinner

At the moment, I have a category Spinner. When user click to the spinner, a drop down list with different categories such as food, services, education, etc. will be displayed.

I get the categories from the database via a cursor and I am able to display what I get from the database to the spinner.

My question is: How can I add one more options to the spinner, after binding all categories to it? What I want to do is to add "All" option to the top of the drop down list when user clicks to the spinner.

```
final DBAdapter mDB = new DBAdapter(getActivity());
            mDB.openDB();

            List<String> categoryFilter = mDB.getItemByFilteredCategory();
            ArrayAdapter<String> filterAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categoryFilter);
            spnFilter.setAdapter(filterAdapter);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code as far what you done.So that I can help you.

Comment: I updated my question with my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could the insert method of the arrayadapter be of any help?

[ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert%28T,%20int%29)

```
filterAdapter.insert("First String", 0); //adds myObject to the first position.
```

Comment: These answer was usedful

Answer (score 0):

To add a value to the spinner use [setAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) method and [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) Class.

**Eg:** ArrayAdapter.add(value);

Add all the values in string.

**For Eg:** Refer these [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html).

```
<resources>     
<string-array name="planets_array">     
<item>Mercury</item>     
<item>Venus</item></string-array>
</resources>
```

If you add values in String,Then set the name in a order which you want in top.

Comment: In this case, it will add to the end of the array. How can I add it to the top of the array? Thanks,

Comment: what happened if it is not helpful to you then show me the code where you add the values.

Comment: Try the ArrayAdapter's insert method with index 0.  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#insert(T, int)